# All notifications cleared after interacting with one notification

Tags: ios, swift, uilocalnotification

The expected behavior for my application is to allow multiple, stacked applications and the user should be able to interact with each notification serperately, however when a user clears one notification or uses one of the action buttons on the notification all of my apps notifications are removed from the lock screen. Is there a way to not clear all notifications after one of them is interacted with?

Notification creator function:

```
func sendNotification (customerName:String) {
    let durationString = String(durationDetected!)
    let content = UNMutableNotificationContent()
    content.title = "Duration: \(durationString)"
    content.subtitle = "Customer Name: \(customerName)"
    //content.body = "Don't forget to bring coffee."
    //content.badge = 1

     let customerFacing = UNNotificationAction(identifier:"yes",
                                            title:"Customer Facing",options:[])
    let notCustomerFacing = UNNotificationAction(identifier:
        "no", title: "Not Customer Facing", options: [])

    /*let changeTime = UNTextInputNotificationAction(identifier:
        "changeTime", title: "Modify Time", options: [])

    let changeName = UNTextInputNotificationAction(identifier:
        "changeName", title: "Modify Customer Name", options: [])*/


    let category = UNNotificationCategory(identifier: "actionCategory",
                                          actions: [customerFacing, notCustomerFacing],
                                          intentIdentifiers: [], options: [])

    content.categoryIdentifier = "actionCategory"


    UNUserNotificationCenter.current().setNotificationCategories(
        [category])

    let trigger = UNTimeIntervalNotificationTrigger(timeInterval: 3,
                                                    repeats: false)

    let eventArrayIndex = LocationService.locationInstance.eventLogArray.count - 1
    let requestIdentifier = String(eventArrayIndex)
    let request = UNNotificationRequest(identifier: requestIdentifier,
                                        content: content, trigger: trigger)

    UNUserNotificationCenter.current().add(request,
                                           withCompletionHandler: { (error) in
                                            // Handle error
    })
}
```

response delegate:

```
func userNotificationCenter(_ center: UNUserNotificationCenter, didReceive
response: UNNotificationResponse, withCompletionHandler completionHandler:
@escaping () -> Void) {

    let eventIndexString = response.notification.request.identifier
        eventIndex = Int(eventIndexString)!
        print("Index \(eventIndex)")

    switch response.actionIdentifier {
    case "yes":
            print("Received")
            LocationService.locationInstance.eventLogArray[eventIndex].status = "customerFacing"
            let currentID = LocationService.locationInstance.eventLogArray[eventIndex].uniqueID
            for (index,element) in LocationService.locationInstance.missedEventArray.enumerated() {
                if element.uniqueID == currentID {LocationService.locationInstance.missedEventArray.remove(at: index)}
            }
            self.commitEventToDatabase(eventObject: LocationService.locationInstance.eventLogArray[eventIndex])
            //self.eventLog.reloadData()
    case "no":
            print(LocationService.locationInstance.eventLogArray.count)
            print("WHHHAT")
            let currentID = LocationService.locationInstance.eventLogArray[eventIndex].uniqueID
            for (index,element) in LocationService.locationInstance.missedEventArray.enumerated() {
                if element.uniqueID == currentID {LocationService.locationInstance.missedEventArray.remove(at: index)}
            }
            LocationService.locationInstance.eventLogArray[eventIndex].status = "notCustomerFacing"
            print(LocationService.locationInstance.eventLogArray.count)
            //self.eventLog.reloadData()
    default:
        break
    }
    completionHandler()
}
```

Comment: Any update on this? Running into a similar problem myself

Comment: I have had no success with this...If you ask a question or figure it out, please let me know